# Newly generated Guardfile is empty

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

I am trying to create a Guardfile inside a small Ruby with some Ruby files and RSpec tests. This not a Rails project.

When I run `gem install guard` I get the following:

```
$ gem install guard
Fetching: listen-1.3.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed listen-1.3.1
Fetching: lumberjack-1.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed lumberjack-1.0.4
Fetching: guard-1.8.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed guard-1.8.3
Installing ri documentation for listen-1.3.1
Installing ri documentation for lumberjack-1.0.4
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for bin/fsevent_watch_guard, skipping
Installing ri documentation for guard-1.8.3
3 gems installed
```

Obviously "\xCF" should have been installed, but it was not. I cannot figure out what this is, and whether it is the likely cause of my problem.

Later, when I try to create a guard for the RSpec tests, the following occurs:

```
$ guard init rspec
19:45:11 - INFO - Writing new Guardfile to /home/kathryn/demo3/Guardfile
19:45:11 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/rspec' or '~/.guard/templates/rspec' or find class Guard::Rspec
```

As the INFO suggests, a new Guardfile is created, but it is filled with a note directing me to the README for the gem rather than a guard for RSpec. If I manually add the guard for RSpec, and then try to run `guard`, the result is:

```
$ guard
19:41:03 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/rspec' or find class Guard::Rspec
19:41:03 - ERROR - cannot load such file -- guard/rspec
19:41:03 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:
> [#] undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
19:41:03 - ERROR - No guards found in Guardfile, please add at least one.
19:41:03 - INFO - Guard is using NotifySend to send notifications.
19:41:03 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
19:41:04 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/kathryn/demo3'
```

I see that the gem cannot find some files that it needs, but I'm not really sure where to go from here. This is my first time using guard. Any help is appreciated.

This is my current Guardfile:

```
guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { "spec" }
end
```

That was not generated automatically. When I first created the Guardfile, the contents were:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme
```

I added the guard for RSpec that appeared as the Standard RubyGem project guard here: https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec. (To be clear, I am not using that gem. It was just an easy place to find the guard.)

Comment: "convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 " is just reporting that it was unable to convert that character from one character set to the other.  Not indicating that it needed to be installed.  You did the command `guard init`?  When you do this, you should end up with a Guardfile, and you will want to edit that for your purposes.  It looks like this happens.  Post your current `Guardfile`.

Comment: @vgoff I have edited my post to include both my current Guardfile and the Guardfile that was generated when I ran `guard init rspec`.

Comment: OK, there is no problem with creating this file on your own.

Comment: Even when I have created the file manually, when I run `guard`, it still generates the series of four ERRORs that I show above.

Comment: `guard/rspec` is the problem.  If you are not using the gem, it seems.  Rename the guard group, from rspec to ... hmm... not sure what you would name it to.  Maybe just `:test`.  In my skeleton that I made to emulate what you are describing this works.  With similar errors.  If you are going to use `rspec` though, go ahead and use the `guard-rspec` gem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once the `guard-rspec` gem is installed, it should "Just Work".

Here are the steps I am doing to get this to load cleanly:

```
▶ gem install guard-rspec rspec
Fetching: rspec-core-2.14.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-core-2.14.5
Fetching: diff-lcs-1.2.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed diff-lcs-1.2.4
Fetching: rspec-expectations-2.14.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-expectations-2.14.2
Fetching: rspec-mocks-2.14.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-mocks-2.14.3
Fetching: rspec-2.14.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-2.14.1
Fetching: guard-rspec-3.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed guard-rspec-3.0.3
Parsing documentation for rspec-core-2.14.5
Installing ri documentation for rspec-core-2.14.5
Parsing documentation for diff-lcs-1.2.4
Installing ri documentation for diff-lcs-1.2.4
Parsing documentation for rspec-expectations-2.14.2
Installing ri documentation for rspec-expectations-2.14.2
Parsing documentation for rspec-mocks-2.14.3
Installing ri documentation for rspec-mocks-2.14.3
Parsing documentation for rspec-2.14.1
Installing ri documentation for rspec-2.14.1
Parsing documentation for guard-rspec-3.0.3
Installing ri documentation for guard-rspec-3.0.3
Done installing documentation for rspec-core, diff-lcs, rspec-expectations, rspec-mocks, rspec, guard-rspec after 15 seconds
Successfully installed rspec-2.14.1
Parsing documentation for rspec-2.14.1
Done installing documentation for rspec after 0 seconds
7 gems installed
```

Once that is done, I do this command:

```
▶ guard init rspec
00:55:13 - INFO - rspec guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
```

And my Guardfile looks like this:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

And when I do the `guard start` command, those errors do not show:

```
▶ guard start
00:57:08 - INFO - Guard uses NotifySend to send notifications.
00:57:08 - INFO - Guard uses Tmux to send notifications.
00:57:08 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
00:57:09 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
00:57:09 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/vgoff/my_gems'
```

Comment: Unsure why the down vote, not that it matters.  But it did get me a 4x4 reputation!  Woot!